# Trying to work on two numbers with operation as $_request['operation']

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value of `$result` but it gives `2+4` as I am giving values `$first=2`, `$second=4` and `$operation= +`.

```
<?php
$first     = $_REQUEST['first'];
$second    = $_REQUEST['second'];
$operation = $_REQUEST['operation'];
echo $result = "$first+$operation+$second";
?>

<form id="dpk-form" action="" method="post">
    <label>First No:</label>  <input name="first" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <label>Second No:</label> <input name="second" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <label>Operation:</label> <input name="operation" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br /><br />
    <label>Result:</label> <input name="result" type="text" /><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way do use operator as variable. You could use `eval()` but it's not the best practice.

I would do it this way:

```
switch  ($_REQUEST['operation']) {
    case '+':
        $result = $first + $second;
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $first - $second;
        break;        
}

echo $result;
```

Of course you should add to `switch` other operators you want to use and of course if you want to use divide, you need to consider dividing by 0.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. `$operation` is the `+`. So you are saying `2+++4`...

Comment: @MarkM Earlier was completely different question

Comment: Did you noticed that `$operation === '+'`?

Comment: Thanks Marcin  But it only works with addition not with subtraction and so forth..

Comment: Then again, I guess it does work: http://codepad.org/8CQphzOX. But only for addition...

Comment: Please don't refer to `eval`. When you deal with user-supplied data (`$_REQUEST`), `eval` is not safe!

Comment: @MarkM It does not work. Simple '+' is converted to 0. You could also write `echo $a + 'x' + $b;` and you would get the same `correct` answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = eval($first.$operation.$second);
```

It’s a really bad and generally dangerous practice to call `eval` in such circumstances, though.

Comment: It's generally bad but **in this special case it is disastrous because it executes arbitrary code supplied by anyone calling this script**. Don't do that!

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke agreed, but not worth a downvote since it solves the problem. Also he gave a hint that it's usage is not recommended. OP should decide by himself. With great power comes great responsibility ...

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDavidPlat. I saw that’s not the master question, developing the huge payment-aware project, therefore I gave such an answer.

Comment: Even if something solves the problem it can be bad. I didn't downvote, though.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke totally! That's why I agreed with you. However Stack Overflow is not a code on demand platform. There are differnt possible solutions to the most of the questions and whosoever is asking a question here, should compare the upsides and the downsides of the answers given by himself.

Answer (score 0):

Eval-free route, but you need to predefine your allowed operations:

```
switch ($operation) {
    case '+':
        echo $first + $second;
        break;
    case '-':
        echo $first - $second;
        break;
    case '/':
        echo $first / $second;
        break;
    case '*':
        echo $first * $second;
        break;
    case '%':
        echo $first % $second;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to work, since `.` is a string concatenatination operator, hence every expression is tried to be casted to a string.

You could use eval here but [I would not recommend the usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

You could either use a switch statement here.

```
switch($_REQUEST['operation'])
{
    case '+':
        $result = $_REQUEST['first'] + $_REQUEST['second'];
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $_REQUEST['first'] - $_REQUEST['second'];
        break;

    // ...
}
```

But that comes with the downside of high maintaining costs and is not very DRY.
If you are more advanced you might want to go with the [strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251076/1420347).